# Modal form not showing when clicking a button

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

This is my HTML

```html
<html lang ="en">
<head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#insertData">Insert Data</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="insertData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="insertLabel">Insert Data</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nm">Full Name</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nm" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="em">Email</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" onclick="saveData()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
 </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I clicked the button, nothing is happening. Somehow if I changed the style link to a url, the button works but doesnt have background color like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxQWC.jpg) I already downloaded the Bootstrap and placed it into my folder.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: yes but the button style is not as it is.

Comment: buttons should look like these https://imgur.com/a/mB1Np

Comment: already removed the `outline` but the button still gray.

Comment: quick question do i really need to include the url in my codes when i already downloaded the BS files. Im confused.

Comment: yep like that with 1 dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from our conversation, you want the `Insert Data` to be colored as primary. Then remove the `outline` in `btn-outline-primary`. You can also easily copy the class from the `Save` button

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div class="container">
    <p></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#insertData">Insert Data</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="insertData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="insertLabel">Insert Data</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="nm">Full Name</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nm" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Full Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="em">Email</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" onclick="saveData()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

And this is the original code *(except the bootstrap's css file, and jquery)*

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p></p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#insertData">Insert Data</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="insertData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="insertLabel">Insert Data</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="nm">Full Name</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nm" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Full Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="em">Email</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" onclick="saveData()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the patience. Do I really need to include the BS url to my codes when I arleady downloaded the BS files from their website?

Comment: What url? You mean like `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`?

Comment: It's okay not to use the url *(actually it is called a [**CDN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network))* if you already downloaded the file, as long as your path is correct.

Comment: Can you check in the Dev Tools if what error you are receiving? Also, change the CDN of jquery to the one that I used

Comment: No error in the console? It really looks like your path is incorrect, or if not, check the filename

Comment: Yes it is fine.

Comment: This one https://imgur.com/a/rfyyE actually works. but modal didnt show again. what am I missing?

Comment: Can you screenshot the website plus the dev tools with the console?

Comment: That is quite weird, anyway, for now use the **CDN** of Bootstrap if it makes the modal work

Comment: doesn cdn works even if i dont have any internet connection?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. What I really can think is that either your path or file name is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You ***should*** import your *bootstrap* and *jquery* into `head`, not in `body`. Check this code.

**edit:** @Swellar's correction : "you can also put the scripts inside . It is just the matter of order of when you will use the scripts and its dependents, so most of the time it is located way above, especially `jquery.min.js`"

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#insertData">Insert Data</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="insertData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="insertLabel">Insert Data</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nm">Full Name</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nm" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="em">Email</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" onclick="saveData()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button still doesnt have any backgrounds. Like the one that I included in my post.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are tagged BS4, but you are using external BS3 js, external jQuery 2.x, and local unkown BS css.

First use correctly BS, read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: I said that I already downloaded the BS files so  I dont need to link the url it to my style tag?